# Uwp binding combobox selected value to Dependency Property

Tags: c#, data-binding, uwp

I have a ComboBox inside a Uwp User Control and I want to bind the SelectedValue property directly to a Dependency Property of the control so I can set/get the value directly

this is the content of the user control

```
<Grid>
    <ComboBox x:Name="clientiList" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        Width="300"
        SelectedValuePath="ClienteNo" 
        DisplayMemberPath="Descrizione" 
        SelectedValue="{Binding idCliente, ElementName=userControl, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</Grid>
```

and this is the code inside the control

```
public int ?idCliente {
    get { return IdCliente;  }
    set { IdCliente = value; }
}
public int ?IdCliente
{
    get { return (int?)GetValue(IdClienteProperty); }
    set { SetValue(IdClienteProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty IdClienteProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("IdCliente", typeof(int?), typeof(ClientiAttiviSelect), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

I see that if I bind the SelectedValue property to the **IdCliente** property when I select a value in the list I see this error in the output window

```
Error: Converter failed to convert value of type 'Windows.Foundation.Int32' to type 'IReference`1<Int32>'; BindingExpression: Path='IdCliente' DataItem='MyAttivita.Features.Cliente.Views.ClientiAttiviSelect'; target element is 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ComboBox' (Name='clientiList'); target property is 'SelectedValue' (type 'Object').
```

If I bind the SelectedValue to the **idCliente** property and use it to update the **IdCliente** property it works.
Why this happens? How can I avoid this duplication?

Comment: What's the reason that the property is of type `int?`? Is the `ClienteNo` property also `int?`? Probably also show the relevant parts of your view model.

Comment: It also doesn't seem to make sense to have an `idCliente` property as wrapper for `IdCliente`. For what purpose? Besides that, the error message shows `Path='IdCliente'`, which does not correspond to the Binding expression in XAML, `{Binding idCliente, ...}`

Comment: Yes, ClienteNo is ?int.  I need the idCliente property wrapper for the binding error that prevents me to propagate the value selected outside the component. I would like to avoid this workaround

Comment: if I use {Binding IdCliente, ...} I have the error, if I use {Binding idCliente, ...} not

Comment: I even cannot run your  code successfully. Could you please upload a minimal reproduced project?